What is Difference between KubernetesManifest@0 and KubernetesManifest@1 in Yaml pipeline?
When reading about the Kubernetes tasks used in pipelines, I can see both KubernetesManifest@0 and KubernetesManifest@1
Whats the difference? And can I use these interchangeably? The documentation says it applied to v0 and v1 tasks respectively. But the examples always seems to show @0
The examples in both the links below always seem to use KubernetesManifest@0 (even for KubernetesManifest@1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-manifest-v0?view=azure-pipelines
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-manifest-v1?view=azure-pipelines

Thanks

The difference of KubernetesManifest@0 and KubernetesManifest@1 is noted in the Remarks of the KubernetesManifest@0 task.

There is a newer version of this task available that provides additional support for targetting a Kubernetes cluster in different ways, using the connectionType property. For more information, see KubernetesManifest@1 and KubernetesManifest@1 service connection remarks


In KubernetesManifest@0 task, you can only use Kubernetes service connection.

In KubernetesManifest@1 task, you can choose different Service connection type.


And can I use these interchangeably?

If you are using Kubernetes Service Connection, both versions of the task can be used. If you need to use Azure Resource Manager Service Connection, you must use the new version of the task.
